# Displaying multiple form_tags on a single page via partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app has a partial that get rendered for every meal object that belongs to a user,, effectively listing out the meals. Each meal has some foods listed underneath that. I have a form_tag and text_field_tag that go right under the last food in each meal that uses autocomplete.

When I type into the first text_field I can see my server processing the request. Although when I type something into the other text_fields below the first one, the server doesn't seem to be processing anything at all.

It seems that the form_tag only gets applied to the first text_field_tag directly below it since chrome console shows a closing  tag  under it.

The form_tag doesn't show up for the other text_field_tags at all.

What's funny is that the default hidden div underneath the form_tag DOES show up for the other form_tags...

Here is my partial

```
<td class=search-form-block>
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "foods", :action => "save_selected"}, method: "post") %>

  <%= text_field_tag 'search_food_text_field', nil, data: { catcomplete_source: search_foods_path } %>

</td>
<td class=remove-td-center> <%= link_to "new food", nil,  {class: "new-food-button"} %> </td>
```

The autocomplete jquery:

```
 $( "#search_food_text_field" ).catcomplete({
   source: $("#search_food_text_field").data('catcomplete-source')
});
```

How can I have each form on the page work the way autocomplete is supposed to, as it does for the first form_tag/text_field_tag?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you've got two separate issues here.

Regarding the form tags, form_tag won't include the closing tag at all unless it's called as a block.  Chrome console is probably filling in the close-form tag automatically, but you're producing malformed HTML source.  In other words, you should do:

```
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "foods", :action => "save_selected"}, method: "post") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'search_food_text_field', nil, data: { catcomplete_source: search_foods_path } %>
  <% end %>
```

For the issue with the auto-completion, you should try using classes rather than ids (because ids need to be unique), then making sure to call the autocomplete on each textfield.  Try declaring your text_field_tags like this:

```
  <%= text_field_tag 'search_food_text_field', nil, data: { catcomplete_source: search_foods_path }, class: 'auto-complete' %>
```

And calling your jQuery like this:

```
$( ".autocomplete" ).each(function() {
  $(this).catcomplete({
   source: $(this).data('catcomplete-source')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ill try this out as soon as I get home.